# Rails methods with default values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have helper function in application_helper.rb file:

```
def nested_attributes(attributes, cn = controller_name.classify)
    attributes.map do |attribute, sub_attributes|
        content_tag(:ul) do
            content_tag(:li, :id => cn+"[#{attribute.id}]") do
                raw(attribute.name+nested_attributes(sub_attributes))
            end
        end
    end.join.html_safe
end
```

and then I calling it from view:

```
<%= nested_attributes @categories.arrange, 'baget_category_id' %>
```

But when I check result, I got Controller name (Which is default value) instead of 'baget_category_id'. When I remove default value, i got an error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2). What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `attribute`?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems you have to pass cn to recurring call:

```
raw(attribute.name+nested_attributes(sub_attributes, cn))
```